# Find out max duplicate number between 1 to N numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm

How can I make this method better?

```
int[] _input = new int[] { 5,45,184,594,14,8,5,184,1841,184,594,5,78,594,14,8,18,4,18,14,8,594};


Dictionary<int, int> _inputDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();

foreach (int i in _input)
{
    if (_inputDictionary.ContainsKey(i))
    {

        _inputDictionary[i] = ++_inputDictionary[i] ;

    }
    else
    {
        _inputDictionary.Add(i,1);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Maximum number repeated is " + _inputDictionary.OrderByDescending(g => g.Value).First().Key + " and it is repeated " + _inputDictionary.OrderByDescending(g => g.Value).First().Value+" times");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` to count the duplicates.

Then you should sort the result and get the first item once, instead of sorting it each time you use it:

```
int[] _input = new int[] {
  5, 45, 184, 594, 14, 8, 5, 184, 1841, 184, 594, 5, 78, 594, 14, 8, 18, 4, 18, 14, 8, 594
};

IGrouping<int, int> max =
  _input.GroupBy(n => n)
  .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
  .First();

Console.WriteLine(
  "Maximum number repeated is " + max.Key +
  " and it is repeated " + max.Count() + " times"
);
```

Comment: Thanks for that.could you explain me how does that linq work internally ?what would be the algorithmic complexity of both of our solutions??I am looking at this problem from interview purpose :)

Comment: @kyle: The `GroupBy` works basically as your use of the dictionary in the original code, so the complexity for that part is O(n). The compexity of a sort is typically O(n log n), but you could improve that to O(n) using a loop instead, as you only need the first item.

Answer (score 1):

I myself am still learning how to be a good citizen of CR (and reviewing helps me to understand the reviewers). I recommend reading [this meta post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions?cb=1).

For me it was at first reading hard to understand this line:

```
           _inputDictionary[i] = ++_inputDictionary[i] ;
```

And why you use `Dictionary` instead of [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb359438%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but got the idea from the printout:

```
   Console.WriteLine("Maximum number repeated is " + _inputDictionary.OrderByDescending(g => g.Value).First().Key + " and it is repeated " + _inputDictionary.OrderByDescending(g => g.Value).First().Value+" times")
```

Which would better be splitted to few more lines to make it more readable, e.g. like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Maximum number repeated is "
+ _inputDictionary.OrderByDescending(g => g.Value).First().Key
+ " and it is repeated " + _inputDictionary
.OrderByDescending(g => g.Value).First().Value
+ " times");
```

Now I understand the purpose of the program - to actually **count the duplicit values** - you should probably describe your intent first stating this at the top.

...and we can look again at the strange line of code:

```
           _inputDictionary[i] = ++_inputDictionary[i] ;
```

I was at first thinking *what is that?* After reading the whole code, I got it - we have to store the incremented value back. I think that it would be better this way:

```
           _inputDictionary[i] = _inputDictionary[i] + 1;
```

Using HashSet with classes that contain both the value and the counter could make the code look more readable, but may impact the speed on the other way. I hope somebody else will address this.

Comment: You don't need to store the value back when you are using the `++` operator. Just `_inputDictionary[i]++;` will do.

Comment: That was a part I was not completely sure about - that it works in C# (not returning reference as in C++). Will it call the setter automatically? I hope so.

Comment: In C# there isn't a separate `++` operator, it is implemented using the `+` operator. So `_inputDictionary[i]++;` is implemented as `_inputDictionary[i] = _inputDictionary[i] + 1;`, so it will write the value back to the dictionary.

Comment: @Guffa [Here is the `++` operator reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx)

Comment: @radarbob: This is more about properties and how they work. `++` gets translated to `+=1` which gets translated to `set(get()+1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the sort at the end. Your algorithm should run in O(n) instead of O(nlgn). You can maintain the maximum duplicate encountered so far in a local variable as you only need the maximum, not the sorted array.

```
int[] _input = new int[] { 5, 45, 184, 594, 14, 8, 5, 184, 1841, 184, 594, 5, 78, 594, 14, 8, 18, 4, 18, 14, 8, 594 };


            Dictionary<int, int> _inputDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            int maxSoFar = int.MinValue;

            foreach (int i in _input)
            {
                if (_inputDictionary.ContainsKey(i))
                {

                    _inputDictionary[i] = ++_inputDictionary[i];
                    if (i > maxSoFar)
                        maxSoFar = i;
                }
                else
                {
                    _inputDictionary.Add(i, 1);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Maximum number repeated is " + maxSoFar + " and it is repeated " + _inputDictionary[maxSoFar] + " times");
```

Answer (score 0):

Firda's made some good points about readability, but I'd like to go a little further.

Firstly, it's recommended that when defining variables, if it's obvious what type the variable is from the right-hand-side, use `var` on the left. This way if you go to change the type later, you only have to change it in one place.

e.g

```
var _inputDictionary = new Dictionary<int,int>();
```

Additionally, it's also recommended not to use the variable's type in its name, or [prefix with underscores](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx).

```
var duplicateCounts = new Dictionary<int,int>();
```

Additionally, I think you can simplify your final statement using [LINQ's Max function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb918740(v=vs.90).aspx) to:

```
int mostDuplicates = duplicateCounts.Keys.Max()
int valueWithMostDuplicates = duplicateCounts[mostDuplicates];

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Maximum number repeated is {0} and it is repeated {1} times",
    valueWithMostDuplicates,
    mostDuplicates));
```